# 「HTML5独自データ属性が指定の値である要素」を削除したい

Tags: javascript, html, html5

下記で「data-hoge="b"である要素(子要素含む)」を削除したいのですが、該当要素を(jQueryではなく)JavaScriptで選択するにはどうすれば良いですか？

```
<main>
  <div class="">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <div class="" data-hoge="a"></div>
        <div class="" data-hoge="b"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` メソッドに与えるセレクタとして、属性の値を持つ[属性セレクタ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax)を用いることで可能だと思います。

属性セレクタを使用することで、属性を持っているかどうか(`[data-hoge]`)、属性値が指定のものそのものかどうか(`[data-hoge="value"]`)、複数指定された属性値の中に一致する値はあるか(`[data-hoge~="value"]`)など、細かい条件によって要素を選択することが出来ます。

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-hoge~='b']").forEach(e => e.outerHTML = "");
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <div class="" data-hoge="a">
          <p>テキスト a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="" data-hoge="b">
          <p>テキスト b</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[data-hoge~='b']").forEach(e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e));
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="">
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <div class="" data-hoge="a">
          <p>テキスト a</p>
        </div>
        <div class="" data-hoge="b">
          <p>テキスト b</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```